# SMB Mount directory and reconnecting

Tags: sharing, mount, smb

I have some trouble with fileserver shares, if the share get's disconnected and reconnected again. The mount dir, e.g. `/Volumes/Data` isn't removed and when the share get's reconnected again, a new directory `/Volumes/Data-1` is created.

However, I need the mount to be available at a static path, so that I can use it in some tools.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue using `automount`

> sudo mkdir -p /mnt/scan
>
> sudo echo "/mnt/scan      auto_scan" >> /etc/auto_master
>
> sudo echo "scansnap -fstype=smbfs ://MYUSER:MYPASS@192.168.1.2/scan/scansnap" >>
>    /etc/auto_scan
>
> sudo chmod 600 /etc/auto_scan
>
> sudo automount -vc
>
> ls -la /mnt/scan/scansnap